# rm not removing directory

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Having a strange issue. Using a script to go through our backup folders and delete any folder not named like the 1st of the month (2023-05-01) and older than 60 days.

It works in the sense that it is going through and erasing the files from the folders but the dated folders themselves (and sub folders) remain.. empty.

What am I missing here.

```
find /backups/stores/ -maxdepth 2 -type d ! -name '????-??-01' -mtime +60 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: does `!` work? I thought it needed  to be `-not`

Comment: @apokryfos I bet it works. `!` is mandated by POSIX, portable. `-not` is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: (1) Any error message from `rm`? (2) Add `-print` just before `-exec` to see what directories actually get to `rm`. (3) Be careful. Without `-mindepth`, the first directory to check will be `/backups/stores/` (it's at depth 0); if `-mtime +60` turns out to be true for it then `find` will run `rm -rf /backups/stores/`.

Comment: Thank you. I added -mindepth 1 to be safe. I also added -print and it returns nothing. I've already ran this script today so it's already purged what its going to purge. So when I am running it again its just returning nothing. Those directories still exist.

Comment: Try to limit yourself to the `find` command and simplify it until you get some results, then return parameters until it stops working.

Comment: Is it possible something is wrong with the folders themselves? For testing I am running as root. All the dir's are owned by root. When I run this same command on a dummy folder structure that I created it works fine. When I running against my backup dir's it doesnt delete the folders.. the files inside are deleted for the desired folders. My backup dir's are just rsync'd files from Windows servers

Comment: What is the type of the filesystem? Is the filesystem healthy?

Comment: xfs and its healthy.

Comment: so here is a fun find.. the modify time on all the DIR's that arent being deleted are the last time i ran the command.. so now those directories are withing the -mtime +60 range... not sure how that happened... but with that being said.. is there an easier way to do this by looking at the dir name and basing off that. The directories are dated. I dont care about the timestamps inside. I want folders that are 1st of month and last 60 days... based on the folder name not contents. Folder names are YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: (4) An act of unlinking anything from a directory is a modification of the directory. (5) "Is there an easier way …?" – It's a new question. This is not how the site works. Please take our short [tour]. You do not ask nor modify questions in comments. You can [edit] the question and substantially change it (not elegant, but as long as there are no answers it should do no harm) or ask a new one.

Comment: Thank you. Yes probably the unlinking.. these folders are all linked to the previous folders.. so its one massive incremental backup. That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but might this be an effect of "ordering"?

Note the order the folders appear in...

```
$ find /etc/d* -type d -printf "%p\n"
```

... and the effect of adding "sort -r" (sort reverse)...

```
$ find /etc/d* -type d -printf "%p\n" | sort -r
```

To avoid such trouble, one might try

```
$ ( cd /etc/dconf/ && find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%p\n" )
```

i.e. use a subtask, which first does a `cd` into the "work folder", which then allows the use of a slightly more direct addressing of the actual folders to act on.

Comment: I doubt it. [One can get errors from trying to delete already deleted directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115863/108618), but once `rm -rf` runs for a right directory, the directory shall not remain.

Comment: Well, something similar to `$ find /etc/dconf/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%p\n"` - might be worth a try. (example for folder structure two deep, with subfolders)

Comment: or even better; `$ ( cd /etc/dconf/ && find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%p\n" )`

Comment: ... edit above inline with comments.