# Complex find statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

Have a script that I use to purge old backup directories. All the directories are named YYYY-MM-DD. The backup directories have links in them as the backups are incremental using the rsync --link-dest. When I run my traditional find statement as it is deleting the links it changes the modified time of the folder so my script in the end deletes all the files but not the actual folders.. as the script looks at the modified time.

`find /backups/stores/ -maxdepth 2 -type d ! -name '????-??-01' -mtime +60 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Is there a easier (better) way to delete these folders based on their name and not their modified time. Since they are already all named YYYY-MM-DD could we compare using the date command or something to look at the names and delete anything with a name older than 60 days and without a 1 in the day field (wanting to keep all first of month folders).

Thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: For the record, I do not think your statement ("as it is deleting the links it changes the modified time of the folder so my script in the end deletes all the files but not the actual folders") explains [what happened](https://superuser.com/q/1802659/432690). You used neither `-depth` nor `-delete`, so `find` does not work depth-first. When a directory is given to `rm -rf`, the deletion affects its parent directory *which has already been tested by `find`*. This is why I advised to use `-print` before `-exec` to make sure you give `rm` exactly the directories you expect.

Comment: I get that with the original issue. The issue is that all the modification times have now been altered. So the original script no longer will work in any capacity as expected as every dir is now returning false. Maybe before I did the first run -print would have helped me see the issue sooner but at this point I need to find a different way to clear these folders.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to solve this backup directory purge issue is to tweak the find statement to focus on the directory names instead of their modified time. No need to worry about those pesky links messing up your script.

Instead of using "find," you can use a nifty combination of "date" and "rm" commands. Let's have the "date" command do the heavy lifting by calculating the date 60 days ago and then use "rm" to clean up those old directories.

```bash
find /backups/stores/ -maxdepth 2 -type d ! -name '????-??-01' -exec sh -c 'dir_date=$(date -d "${1##*/}" "+%Y%m%d"); sixty_days_ago=$(date -d "60 days ago" "+%Y%m%d"); if [ $dir_date -lt $sixty_days_ago ]; then rm -rf "$1"; fi' sh {} \;
```

Simply paste this into your terminal. It will zap those old directories that are older than 60 days but keep those special first-of-the-month ones intact.

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly.